# Why odom/filtered output on map frame is moving?

Tags: ros, navigation, gps

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, im working on a navigation system.

I am using two instances of ekf filter from robot_localization package. I am obteinig that in the "odom" frame, i receive the gps signal with the odometry_map signal with a  good performance, the signals are near enough to the robot whe it is static.

But when i visualice what is happening in the "map" frame, the robot is constantly moving around the ground, and the gps, and the /odometry/global signals are moving together with the robot.

So, the idea that i have is that the "odom -> map" trasnform frame is constantly moving alone. Why i am getting that? Is it becuase the GPS signal ? I am watching that sometimes the robot move in a area that more than 3m of error, which is usually the average gps error.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/397537/why-odom/filtered-output-on-map-frame-is-moving?/) by [Johart24](https://answers.ros.org/users/77008/johart24/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2022-03-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is normal behavior if you configured it according to the [documentation](http://docs.ros.org/en/noetic/api/robot_localization/html/integrating_gps.html).

Idea is that local EKF handles wheel odometry and IMU to provide continuous vehicle trajectory (odom->base transform).
Global EKF takes global position from GPS and uses it to provide map->odom transform. This can (and most probably will) jump around due to GPS inaccuracies.

---

Originally posted by [Nikodem](https://answers.ros.org/users/29718/nikodem/) with karma: 61 on 2022-03-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Johart24](https://answers.ros.org/users/77008/johart24/) on 2022-03-14**:
Hey thanks for answer.  I have a concern. If i want to publish a gps coordinate waypoint, this inaccuracies in the map_frame are gonna interfere on the trajectory path creation?

**Comment by [Johart24](https://answers.ros.org/users/77008/johart24/) on 2022-03-14**:
I share you a capture of how it looks like. https://ibb.co/D5Jv1tZ